# How to run microsoft BotBuilderLocation C# sample using VisualStudioCode?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, botframework

I downloaded project from https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Location , extracted and opened the CSHARP folder using VisualStudioCode. I tried to run the project from terminal using command

```
dotnet run --project BotBuilderLocation.sln
```

But I'm getting multiple errors as follows:

> D:\InsuranceClaimSolution\BotBuilder-Location-master\CSharp\BotBuilderLocation.Sample\BotBuilderLocation.Sample.csproj(158,3):
> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.416\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
> was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> "C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.416\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets"
> is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.416\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5):
> error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6
> were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
> (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your
> application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
> [D:\InsuranceClaimSolution\BotBuilder-Location-master\CSharp\BotBuilderLocation.Tests\BotBuilderLocation.Tests.csproj]
> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.416\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5):
> error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6
> were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack
> (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your
> application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at
> https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
> [D:\InsuranceClaimSolution\BotBuilder-Location-master\CSharp\BotBuilderLocation\BotBuilderLocation.csproj]
>
> The build failed. Fix the build errors and run again.

I'm new to dotnet and VisualStudioCode. I tried to search and fix these errors, but I'm not understanding how to fix this using VisualStudioCode. I've dotnet version 3.1.416. There are too many files and too many lines in this project, which are referring to a different dotnet version. Some target files are also not found. Now I'm confused from where to get these missing target files, what to do inorder to retarget this project to my current dotnet version.

Can someone please help?

Comment: As per the error message .Net version v4.6 is missing in your system, So you are using it .Net version 3.1.416. Upgrade or install the respective version in your system  [click here to download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net461)

Comment: Hi @RajeeshMenoth . Thanks for reply. Can I run this code with .Net version 3.1.416? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: I am not sure which version of the .net framework is required for the development activity. In that case if it is more than that of the current version ( .net version 3.1 ) then you need to use v4.6 as per the package dependency.

Comment: Make sure you have both [.NET](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download) and [.NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/3.1) installed on your system, and try again. These are two different toolkits and some projects reference packages in both of them.

You might also have better luck using full Visual Studio if on Windows.